# Multiplicative Persistence - Highest persistence found?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, experimental-mathematics, digits

tried to ask on the math reddit but got deleted due to my account being new.

Is the record for highest multiplicative persistence found still 11? As I may have just found a number with persistence of 12.

Feel like it might be a bug, but whenever I run the code on any numbers with known persistence, it always outputs expected result. Wondering if anybody here knows if this is significant, or if others have already done this. Thanks

Comment: What is "multiplicative persistence"?  Why would it be a bug if running code (what code?) on numbers with known persistence outputs the expected result?  \\ Also, MO is for research-level mathematics, not as a replacement for being unable to post to [r/math](https://www.reddit.com/r/math).  You might have better luck at our sister site [MSE](http://math.stackexchange.com), once you clarify your terms.  (Also also—unless you just want to advertise, which is not appropriate here or on MSE—once you define what multiplicative persistence is, you should give the number you think brings it to 12.)

Comment: Not sure if this reply button is replying to you or my post in general, but yeah sorry about that. Just don't know where else to ask. 

Multiplicative persistence as in, multiply every digit in a number by each other, how many steps to reach a single digit number. Highest persistence I can see found online is 11. So the code is just taking a number and multiplying the digits together until > 10. Pretty hard to believe there would be a bug in the code since it's so simple, but yeah. Sorry about not explaining.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/455497/multiplicative-persistence-highest-persistence-found#comment1179268_455497), as I have just [indicated](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/455497/multiplicative-persistence-highest-persistence-found#comment1179266_455497), once you say what your terms mean, this might do better on MSE.  Or it is possible that it will be appropriate for MO, but it's impossible to say unless you define multiplicative persistence.

Comment: Still no idea if this comment is notifying you as a reply, or just a standard comment, but I pushed enter trying to go to next line earlier, I meant to explain in my original reply, my bad. ^ Edited first comment.

Comment: Multiplicative Persistence is defined here: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MultiplicativePersistence.html#:~:text=Multiply%20all%20the%20digits%20of,the%20multiplicative%20digital%20root%20of%20.  I would be shocked that it has a finite bound, it just appears that it takes very very large numbers to move the persistence needle. In this case the wolfram article suggests that there is no number with less than 233 digits and this individual if they are to be believed says they could not find a number with less than 400 digits:

Comment: and this individual if they are to be believed says they could not find a number with less than 400 digits: https://www.reddit.com/r/numberphile/comments/b5ognh/no_multiplicative_persistence_of_12_up_to_400/  here is a link to their code https://github.com/Davipb/MultiplicativePersistence/ from that same reddit post are you somehow searching numbers beyond 400 digits in length?

Comment: Yeah I've seen that post. Number I found has 500 digits ^. Still don't know how to send direct replies @SidharthGhoshal

Comment: Is it just an arbitrary number or do you have a proof its the smallest such number? Because I could easily make high persistence by say consider a number of just 1,000 digits of 9 and then measuring its persistence (it would be large). Actually, you should just post it on ArXiV and see if anyone manages to beat it as a quick way of checking

Comment: @SidharthGhoshal 

Just tried that out for fun lol, goes to 0 after 1 step as if you get a number with a zero in it anywhere, the process will always terminate on the next step.

But also, no, I do not have proof this is the smallest such number, just a such number. As far as I look online, nobody has found any number with a persistence of 12, so I doubt this is the smallest one as well.

Comment: @SidharthGhoshal, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/455497/multiplicative-persistence-highest-persistence-found#comment1179276_455497), I think the arXiv folks would probably frown on the use of the arXiv as a proof checker / "challenge" site.

Comment: Double checked it with a handful of others code that's been posted online for this. Definitely 12, not even sure how I would go about proving it's the smallest one unless I was gonna brute force numbers up to ~500 digits (lol). Not sure what arXiv is, but tomorrow when I wake up I'll check it out and see what they think. Thanks guys

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/455497/multiplicative-persistence-highest-persistence-found#comment1179290_455497), if you are not familiar with the arXiv, then please study it very carefully before submitting.  If you do not have a university affiliation, then you will probably have best luck with your submission being accepted if you have an endorsement, for example, from a math professor with whom you have discussed your work.  If you do not have such a person yet, then it is probably more appropriate to build such a relationship and discuss there than to submit to the arXiv.

Comment: @mwt2212 do you want to just post the number here? It’s simple enough to check and you have now piqued my curiosity

Comment: I wonder if one can submit such a large number to https://oeis.org/A003001 ... items submitted to OEIS are checked by someone before being accepted.

Comment: @Gerald: Yes, OEIS accepts large numbers in so-called b-files; the [guideline](https://oeis.org/wiki/B-files) says the lines in the file should not "generally" exceed 1000 characters, so ~500 digits would be fine. But there is no reason to believe that this supposed number would *belong* to A003001; even if it has persistence 12 (which already seems unlikely), there is nothing to suggest it would be the *smallest* such number, and that's what A003001 is supposed to contain.

Comment: One more decimal-sensitive artificial definition...

Answer (score 12):

First, to your direct question: "Is the record still 11", the answer is "yes", according to a variety of sources ([MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MultiplicativePersistence.html#:%7E:text=Multiply%20all%20the%20digits%20of,the%20multiplicative%20digital%20root%20of%20), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_of_a_number), [OEIS A003001](https://oeis.org/A003001)). If anyone has found a new record, at least it is not in these sources yet.

Now for some general advice.

Finding a number that has high multiplicative persistence is a prime example of "hard to find, easy to verify". Given a (say) 500-digit number, it only takes a few lines of code, and an eyeblink of computer time, to compute its persistence.

My advice in such situations is:

> *If you think you have succeeded in the difficult "find" task, surely you should spend a reasonable effort in the relatively easy "verify" task before announcing your result.*

So, if you think you have found such a small number with persistence 12, surely you should first verify your claim with some simple computer code. If that seems to succeed, perhaps double-check using another implementation, perhaps in a different language, perhaps on a different computer. After a reasonable amount of verification succeeds -- OK, perhaps then it is time to think about telling others.

The comments in OEIS claim various lower bounds on the size of a number of persistence 12: a comment in 2019 claims $10^{20585}$, and a comment in 2023 claims $2.67 \times 10^{30000}$. A 500-digit number would contradict both, so all the more reason to double-check.

For completeness, here is straightforward SageMath code to verify such claims. It can be run online in [this SageMathCell](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJx9j8FqwzAQRO8G_8NiMEjUDVIgtDG4935D2gST3TQL9lbIcvL7UWITuz14TivNjPQW6QTIPxw6JbpME4hCqGD3PczXMzcEMjp3SQGe2poFyccg8qX9RRVvrdFTCle1cySontnR9BR6L4BTNE0wQrR9E9g1fKwDX-jgyHfcBZIjTWAc_zPD6DxLUFmOJeSYQQ6KC9H6D_RHZc0cPLadj6zPfWe8DC8V2Om8-P5ofgY4190_cpiRx-qXDOV7NU0Wlly_PfT-0HarF8PW7DfGvFp9A6ZsemA=&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==).

```
def digits(n):
    d = []
    while n:
        n, remainder = divmod(n, 10)
        d.append(remainder)
    return d
        
def multiplicative_persistence(n):
    i = 0
    print("%d: %d" % (i,n))
    while n>=10:
        n = prod(digits(n))
        i += 1
        print("%d: %d" % (i,n))
    print("It has multiplicative persistence %d\n" % (i))

multiplicative_persistence(277777788888899)
multiplicative_persistence(10^500-1)
```

The output from these numbers is:

```
0: 277777788888899
1: 4996238671872
2: 438939648
3: 4478976
4: 338688
5: 27648
6: 2688
7: 768
8: 336
9: 54
10: 20
11: 0
It has multiplicative persistence 11

0: 99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999
1: 1322070819480806636890455259752144365965422032752148167664920368226828597346704899540778313850608061963909777696872582355950954582100618911865342725257953674027620225198320803878014774228964841274390400117588618041128947815623094438061566173054086674490506178125480344405547054397038895817465368254916136220830268563778582290228416398307887896918556404084898937609373242171846359938695516765018940588109060426089671438864102814350385648747165832010614366132173102768902855220001
2: 0
It has multiplicative persistence 2
```